# Can @Persisted property be also @objc in Realm

Tags: swift, realm

Realm database offers, since version 10.10.0, to declare stored properties with `@Persisted` annotation, replacing the `@objc dynamic` annotation.

The [documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/swift/model-data/object-models/#persisted-property-attributes) is pretty clear about the transition: mixing has serious consequences.

> If you mix @Persisted and @objc dynamic property declarations within a class definition, any property attributes marked as @objc dynamic will be ignored.

But I can't find any information about a property that would be annotated with `@Persisted @objc`, for properties that are accessed from Objective-C code, or for the simplicity of getting a `String` out of a `#keyPath`.

So for example, would both these properties would get persisted?

```
@Persisted var token: String?

@Persisted @objc var lastRegisteredDate: Date?
```

Edit: Here's an example of a compiling error with a Swift property marked with `@Persisted` that is accessed from some objective-c code.

Model:

```
@objc
public class PushNotificationSettings: Object {

    @Persisted
    public var registrationId: String?
}
```

Objective-c code:

```
// declaration of a property to be used in a block. 
// The compiler will complain that "Property 'registrationId' not found on object of type 'PushNotificationSettings *'"
__block NSString *registrationId = self.settings.registrationId;
```

Comment: Both of those properties would be persisted but why `@Persisted @objc` in the first place? You can access Realm objects from either Swift or Objc. What is the use case getting String out of a keypath on a Realm property? Maybe if we could see what you're attempting to do (code wise) we could provide a more concrete answer. Update the question with an example and we'll take a look.

Comment: I get a compiler error, saying that Objective-C code can't find properties marked with `@Persisted` only; is there something I should be looking at? I edited the question with an example.
As for your request of examples, I made some progress. For example, `sorted(byKeyPath keyPath: String, ...)` can be replaced by `sorted<T>(by keyPath: KeyPath<Account, T>, ...)`. I also changed `NSPredicate` with filters (although I did not see an equivalent to `NSCompoundPredicate`). So you are correct to challenge the #keyPath angle.

Comment: Realm fully supports nice type-safe queries. For example, a Realm Person model with a `name` property; the sorted query by name would be `let results = realm.objects(Person.self).sorted(by: \.name)`. Is there a reason that type of function is not being used and you're either using a direct keypath string search or generics? Realm also supports both predicates as well as compound predicates but again, type-safe is super convenient. Totally off topic but what's the use case for @objc code at this point - is it a legacy project?

Comment: Yes, it's a decade+ old project and some parts are still in Obj-C. Realm usage also dates back a few years. I'm trying to improve the codebase while minimizing the changes to legacy code (aka not refactoring the class that consumes those properties).
I've added `@objc` to every `@Persisted` property that requires it. This way it compiles. You're saying it will be persisted like other `@Persisted`-only properties?
Thank you for the query example. I am migrating to that API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So for example, would both these properties would get persisted?

Yes. Taking the code in the question and adding it to a Realm object:

```
class Test: Object {
    @Persisted var token: String?
    @Persisted @objc var lastRegisteredDate: Date?
}
```

and then writing it to Realm

```
let t = A_Test()
t.token = "Hello, World"
t.lastRegisteredDate = Date()

try! realm.write {
    realm.add(t)
}
```

results in both properties being populated and persisted

[image]