# Realm: @Persisted(primaryKey: bool) migrated from static func primaryKey()

Tags: swift, realm

I am in the process of removing all `@objc dynamic` annotations from Realm objects to use the more modern `@Persisted` annotation.

While it's been good for a lot of the code, I am running into issues, one of which being related to the object primary key. [Here's the doc](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/swift/model-data/object-models/#specify-a-primary-key). Let's take this example:

```swift
class MyObject: Object {
    
    @objc public dynamic var uuid = ""

    // many other properties...

    override public static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        "uuid"
    }
}
```

This would become this:

```swift
class MyObject: Object {
    @Persisted(primaryKey: true) @objc public var uuid: String
}
```

But running the tests outputs this error:

```
Error Domain=io.realm Code=10 "Migration is required due to the following errors:
- Primary Key for class 'MyObject' has been removed." UserInfo={Error Name=SchemaMismatch, NSLocalizedDescription=Migration is required due to the following errors:
- Primary Key for class 'MyObject' has been removed., Error Code=10}
```

Note 1: the `@objc` annotation is required because this property is accessed from Objective-C code. I also tested this case without the `@objc` annotation and the result is the same. This is possible, according to [this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77880917).

Note 2: in both cases (before/after), the `uuid` is initialized this way:

```swift
override public required init() {
    super.init()

   self.uuid = UUID().uuidString
}
```

Could this be because another issue in the schema, in a related object? For example, for another Model I have "translated"

```swift
    @objc public private(set) dynamic var id: Int = 1

    public var categoryList = List<PersistableIdentifiableObject>()

    override public required init() {
        super.init()
    }

    override public class func primaryKey() -> String? {
        #keyPath(MyObject.id)
    }
```

with

```swift
    @Persisted(primaryKey: true) public private(set) var id: Int

    @Persisted public var categoryList = List<PersistableIdentifiableObject>()

    override public required init() {
        super.init()
        id = 1 // Yes, this is meant to be this way.
    }
```

Thank you for any help regarding this.

Comment: I have continued my experiments. Do the type of the primaryKey is required to be optional?

Comment: *This would become: @Persisted(primaryKey: true) @objc*. No, and that's not valid. It would ultimately be *@Persisted(primaryKey: true) var _id: ObjectId* (or a UUID) and primary keys are never optional. Along with that, the current primary key is `uuid` but the new object does not have that uuid (or any) primary key assigned (it's required!). Do you want to maintain that `uuid` as the primary key or do you want your objects to have a *new* primary key and keep the `uuid` as just a property? What is this `List<PersistableIdentifiableObject>()` for? Also use `RealmSwift.List` instead of `List`

Comment: What do you mean, my new object does not have a primary key assigned? I have `@Persisted(primaryKey: true) @objc public var uuid: String` in my example. Isn't that my primary key?
My primary goal is to keep the schema the same (ie not doing a migration). So when the primary key was returning a `String?`, for example, with this code: `override public class func primaryKey() -> String?`, I need the "new" primary key to still be of type `String?` to avoid a migration. 
I will look into the use of `List` vs `RealmSwift.List`, as it's not my code.

Comment: The `List` type in the code snippets really is of type `RealmSwift.List`. I hope this answers your question.

Comment: That one line was split making it look like two lines of code. I edited the question and made it one line. `List` can create a collisions with SwiftUI `List`, so declaring it `RealmSwift.List` is safer.

Comment: There's code in the question that won't work at all and other code that's causing the error. For example, your initial primary key is "uuid" but is then "id" so the primary key was removed. hence the error. This`override public required init` is not needed nor `super.init()` and also, the initial primary key was a string, now it's an Int. Take a look at [Models](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/swift/model-data/object-models/) and trying making your models look like the Dog object in the guide or as the Project object further down. Do init in a `convenience init` including `self.init()`

Comment: Oh - and perhaps a typo, but the initializer listed `override public required init()` with `let uuid = UUID().uuidString` would initialize a LOCAL only variable called `uuid` and would not initialize the `uuid` class var. (initializing a var with let or var within a function makes that var only local to that function)

Comment: Last thing - *Note 1: the @objc annotation is required* - please re-read the answer linked in your question (I wrote it) as objc is NOT required in that use case.

Comment: Correct: the `let uuid` part is a typo (or part of the code and the truncation makes this appear to be an error). 
The `@objc` annotation is required because some Objc-C code reads the property. It's not obvious from the question, though...
Thank you for your comments, they provide clarity! For everything, but I appreciate especially the part about the init.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues with the code in the question but let me take a crack at an explanation and answer.

So this won't work

```
override public static func primaryKey() -> String? {
   "uuid"
}
```

as "uuid" would need to be returned, like this

```
override public static func primaryKey() -> String? {
   return "uuid"
}
```

Also note that in the above case, the primaryKey is a String? so making it an Int work work

```
@Persisted(primaryKey: true) public private(set) var id: Int
```

and don't do this with Realm objects as they need a convenience init, not an override.

```
override public required init() {
   super.init()
```

--

Now - addressing the issue:

Back in the day with @objc here's how an object with a primary key was defined.

```
class Dog: Object {
    @objc dynamic var id = ""
    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "id"
    }
}
```

Noting that the primaryKey function returns the *name* of the primary key property (not it's value) and is *optional*

Now-days we do the same thing like this, ensuring it's still an optional String. This will flow from @objc to Swift without a migration (assuming the property is the same)

```
class Dog: Object {
    @Persisted(primaryKey: true) var id: String?
}
```

if you want the primary key to be an int, and initialized to 1 every time, here's the code - keep in mind that primaryKeys must be unique so be sure to change the value on new objects before writing!

```
@Persisted(primaryKey: true) var id = 1
```

If you want to initialize a Realm object with provided values upon instantiation, do it in a convenience init ensuring `self.init()` is called to let Realm initialize the object as a Realm object

```
class Dog: Object {
    @Persisted(primaryKey: true) var _id: ObjectId //generally preferred
    @Persisted var name = "" //or provide a default value

    //if not providing a default value for name, use this
    convenience init(withName: String) {
        self.init()
        self.name = withName
    }
}
```

then

```
let dog = Dog(withName: "Spot")
```